# Making value form arryay Jquery?

Tags: jquery, each

I have this array

```
var activeId = 1;

var getAll = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "CEo",
    "office": "NY",
    "active": "Yes"

}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "CEo",
    "office": "NY",
    "active": "Yes"

}]
```

What i need is to get only member with activeId = 1, and than create new var that i can alert?

tried something like this, but i have no luck?

```
$.each(getAll, function(_, val) {
    if (val.id == activeId) {
        name = val.name;
        position = val.position;
        office = val.office;
    }
});

alert(position);
```

Comment: is alert not showing.

Comment: It showing but in all name, position, office i got the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [jquery grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function.

```js
var activeId = 1;

var getAll = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John",
  "position": "CEo",
  "office": "NY",
  "active": "Yes"

}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "John",
  "position": "CEowe",
  "office": "NY",
  "active": "Yes"

}];

var filtered = jQuery.grep(getAll, function(n, i) {
  return (n.id == activeId);
});

for (var item in filtered) {
  document.write("Id:" + filtered[item].id + " Name:" + filtered[item].name + " position:" + filtered[item].position);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please update your array

var activeId = 1;

```
var getAll = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "CEo",
    "office": "NY",
    "active": "Yes"

}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Austin",
    "position": "Manager",
    "office": "US",
    "active": "Yes"

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variables outside the loop :)

http://jsfiddle.net/gwwtukha/3/

```
var name, position, office;

$.each(getAll, function (_, val) {
if (val.id == activeId) {
    name = val.name;
    position = val.position;
    office = val.office;
    //alert(position);
}
});
alert(position);
```

Comment: But how to declare that var in main scope?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getAll = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "CEo",
    "office": "NY",
    "active": "Yes"

}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "CEo",
    "office": "NY",
    "active": "Yes"
}];

getAll = $.map(getAll, function (item) {
    return (item['active'] === 'Yes'? item : null);
});
```

This will give you an array with the two objects, you can't alert these to the user you have to make them into a format alert can handle such as string:

```
getAll = JSON.stringify(getAll);
alert(getAll);
```

But you can always inspect the items with an inspector tool if you print the to the console like so:

```
console.log(getAll);
```